# Do AND, OR strings have special meaning in PLY?

Tags: python, parsing, ply

When using PLY (http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/) I've noticed what seems to be a very strange problem: when I'm using tokens like `&` for conjunction, the program below works, but when I use `AND` in the same place, PLY claims syntax error.

Program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
import os

from ply import lex

import ply.yacc as yacc

parser = None
lexer = None


def flatten_list(lst):
    flat = []
    for x in lst:
        if isinstance(x, list):
            flat.extend(flatten_list(x))
        else:
            flat.append(x)
    return flat


############## Tokenization ##############

tokens = (
    'number',
    'lparen',
    'rparen',
    'textw',
    'titlew',
    'qword',
    'AND'
)

t_lparen = r'\('
t_rparen = r'\)'
t_textw = r'TEXTW:'
t_titlew = r'TITLEW:'
t_qword = r'\w+'
t_AND = r'AND'


def t_number(t):
    r'\d+'
    t.value = int(t.value)
    return t


t_ignore = ' \t'


def t_error(t):
    raise ValueError(
        'Illegal character "{}" at position {}, query text: {}'.format(t.value[0], t.lexpos, t.lexer.lexdata))


lexer = lex.lex()



################# Parsing #################


def p_querylist_boolop(p):
    """querylist : subquery AND subquery"""
    print >> sys.stderr, 'p_querylist', list(p)
    p[0] = []
    p[0].append(p[1])
    p[0].append(p[3])


def p_subquery(p):
    """subquery : lparen querykw qwordseq rparen"""
    print >> sys.stderr, 'p_subquery', list(p)
    p[0] = flatten_list(p[3])


def p_querykw(p):
    """querykw : textw
                | titlew"""
    print >> sys.stderr, 'p_querykw', list(p)
    p[0] = p[1]


def p_qwordseq(p):
    """qwordseq : qwordseq qword
                  | qwordseq number
                  | qword
                  | number"""
    print >> sys.stderr, 'p_qwordseq', list(p)
    if p[0]:
        p[0].extend(p[1:])
    else:
        p[0] = p[1:]



def p_error(p):
    global parser
    if p:
        tok = parser.token()
        if tok:
            msg = 'Syntax error in input, token "{}" at position {}, query text: {}'.format(tok.value, tok.lexpos,
                                                                                            lexer.lexdata)
            raise ValueError(msg)
    msg = 'Syntax error at the end of input, query text: {}'.format(lexer.lexdata)
    raise ValueError(msg)


parser = yacc.yacc()
# parser = yacc.yacc(debug=0, write_tables=0)


def parse_query(q):
    return parser.parse(q)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    query_texts = ["""(TEXTW: one article) AND (TEXTW: two books)"""]
    for qt in query_texts:
        res = parse_query(qt)
        print '***', res
```

This produces:

```
ValueError: Syntax error in input, token "(" at position 19, query text: ( TEXTW: abc ) AND ( TEXTW: aaa )
```

However, when I change the following to:

```
t_AND = r'&'
query_texts = ["""(TEXTW: one article) & (TEXTW: two books)"""]
```

..it works just fine:

```
*** [['one', 'article'], ['two', 'books']]
```

Comment: The problem is presumably that the string “`AND`” is going to be matched by `t_qword = r'\w+'` in the first `p_qwordseq` production, i.e. you need to disambiguate your grammar.

Answer (score 1):

Ply has a slightly eccentric approach to ordering token regular expressions, in part because it depends on the underlying python regular expression library. Tokens defined with functions, such as your `number` token, are recognuzed in the order they appear, and unlike many lexical scanner generators, Ply makes no attempt to perform a longest match. Tokens defined by assignment -- all your other token types -- have lower priority than functions, and are placed in order by decreasing length (of the regular expression).

The Ply manual (section 4.3) strongly suggests not using variable assignment style for keyword tokens such as `AND`, because the pattern `r'AND'`, for example, will recognize the first three characters of, for example, `ANDROGYNOUS`, which you would probably expect to be a variable.
Instead, it recommends using a function with a simple pattern to first recognize all keywords and variables as simple words, and then use a dictionary to recognize the specific keywords. Sample code and a less telegraphic explanation are in the Ply manual (in the section I cited above).